# Android - Back button behavior

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android

I have a project with 2 activities, the first one is the "SplashActivity" - where I load some network data - the second one, the MainActivity.

Inside of my MainActivity I have a fragment and inside of this fragment a webview. My first point is, when the user clicks on back button, the SplashScreen is open again.

The back button should behave like:

- When the user doesn't navigate inside of my webview, close the app.
- When the user navigates in webview, use the back history of the browswer.

I read about back stack here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-webviews

I didn't understand at all how it should work, because I have all cases "mixed". Anyone knows what should I do to fix this problem?

Any idea or sample code will be appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Define Webview wb as a global variable. Then try this;

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(wb.canGoBack() == true){
                    wb.goBack();
                }else{
                     new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Application will be closed")
                     .setMessage("Close app?")
                     .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             finish();
                             System.exit(0);
                         }
                     }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi, looks like what I need, thanks. I just have one question, how can I access my webview inside of my fragment from my activity? Or should I implement this code inside of my fragment?

Comment: I just realized, I cant implement inside of my fragment because there are functions from activity, like finish().

Comment: If you can show those parts of your code maybe i can help you. I didn't use this for fragment.

Comment: Hey, Its too much code hehehe.. anyway, I have a webview inside of a fragment and a fragment inside of an activity... I dont know how to access my webview from my activity.

Comment: I think is not possible to use finish and everything inside of fragment, right?

Comment: You can use getActivity() like this getActivity().finish(); in your fragment class